# Spring 5 Webclient throw exception in doAfterSuccessOrError

Tags: java, spring, reactor-netty

I'm a java 7 developer (finally) taking his first steps in java 8.  A lot of these things are still new to me.  I'm trying to use the spring 5 WebClient since the documentation states RestTemplate will be moved away from in favor of WebClient.

```
        webClient
                .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.pathSegment("api", "payments").build())
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(createPostRequest(paymentConfirmationData)))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .doAfterSuccessOrError((clientResponse, throwable) -> {
                    if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()
                        || clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                         logger.error("POST request naar orchestration layer mislukt, status: [{}]", clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class));
                         Mono.error(throwable);
                    } else {
                        logger.error("POST request naar orchestration layer gelukt");
                    }
                })
                .block();
```

I'm trying to throw an exception in the .doAfterSuccesOrError.  However I can't use throw throwable cause then it just adds a try catch around it.  I read a few articles and this is my last attempt by adding Mono.error(throwable) but since there is no return I'm pretty sure this is the reason there is no effect.

This is a POST call that returns a 204 No Content on success.  At the moment I'm getting a 422 although that shouldn't be important in this particular issue.

Can someone teach me how to throw exceptions back to the calling environment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special method for handling the status codes. More [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve)

Your code should look like

```
webClient.method(HttpMethod.POST)
         .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.pathSegment("api", "payments").build())
         .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(createPostRequest(paymentConfirmationData)))
         .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
         .retrieve()
         .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxServerError, response -> ...)
         .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> ...)
         ...
         .block();
```

Remember that when `onStatus` is used, if the response is expected to have content, then the `onStatus` callback should consume it. If not, the content will be automatically drained to ensure resources are released.

Comment: Will this work for exchange() as well, cause I notice you use retrieve().  I've read the following

Note that (unlike retrieve()), with exchange(), there are no automatic error signals for 4xx and 5xx responses. You have to check the status code and decide how to proceed.

I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with the following code eventually

```
webClient
        .method(HttpMethod.POST)
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.pathSegment("api", "payments").build())
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(createPostRequest(paymentConfirmationData)))
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchange()
        .doOnSuccess((clientResponse) -> {
            if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()
                    || clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                logger.error("POST request naar orchestration layer mislukt, status: [{}]", clientResponse.statusCode());
                throw new RuntimeException("POST request naar orchestration layer mislukt");
            } else {
                logger.error("POST request naar orchestration layer gelukt");
            }
        })
        .doOnError((throwable) -> {
            logger.error("POST request naar orchestration layer mislukt");
            throw new RuntimeException("POST request naar orchestration layer mislukt", throwable);
        })
        .block();
```

Answer (score 2):

For those searching on how to approach exception and error handling.  Have a look at this reference document on the Reactor Project: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#_error_handling_operators